# Bootgrid append method

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

Im breaking my head and cant figure out how to append data, just for testing pourpuses i did this :

```
              var JSONINFO = {"rows": [{"id": 19, "sender": "123@test.de", "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00", "status":"Garantia"},{"id": 19, "sender": "123@test.de", "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00", "status":"Garantia"} ]};

              var result = [];
              for(var i in JSONINFO) result.push([i, JSONINFO [i]]);
              $("#grid-basic").bootgrid().bootgrid("append",result.rows);
```

but cannot insert data in the table ... can anyone clarify the format that the array should have ?, or a more comprehensive example? ... Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my grid.  The problem was that I was loading my grid with ajax.

**Removing the** `ajax: true` and/or setting it to the default `false` solved the "append", "remove" and "clear" problem but I had to solve the loading problem.

In my case, I decided not using the grid "append" function and reload the grid data with a server side call. `$("#myGrid").bootgrid('reload')`

I am not happy with the solution but at least I found the problem I had

```js
var grid = $("#myGrid").bootgrid({
        ajax: false,                    
                formatters: {
            "commands": function (column, row) {
                return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-edit\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"fa fa-pencil\"></span></button> " +
                    "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-delete\" data-row-id=\"" + row.id + "\"><span class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></span></button>";
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use it like this:

```
var JSONINFO = {"rows": [{"id": 19, "sender": "123@test.de", "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00", "status":"Garantia"},{"id": 19, "sender": "123@test.de", "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00", "status":"Garantia"} ]};

$("#grid-basic").bootgrid("append", JSONINFO.rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
bootgrid("append",result.rows);
```

with:

```
bootgrid("append",result.d);
```

Comment: I don't understand what `result.d` is referring to

Answer (score 1):

Just pass JASON

```
var JSONINFO = [{"id": 19, "sender": "123@test.de", "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00", "status":"Garantia"},{"id": 19, "sender": "123@test.de", "received": "2014-05-30T22:15:00", "status":"Garantia"} ];

grid.bootgrid("append", JSONINFO);
```

Pay attention to remove "rows" from JASON...

Comment: JSON. why are are you calling is JASON?